# FD_ISSET return false after select() return 1

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I use `select()` to support a keep alive attribute for an HTTP server. But `FD_ISSET()` returns false after `select()` returns 1. It occurs when I try to load one page in a browser. When I close it and open new pages,  all works fine.

Here is the snippet of code from the function that reads a request and sends the response:

```
do {

    tv.tv_sec = TIMEOUT_SECS;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(arg->sock, &readfds);
    result = select(arg->sock + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    printf("SELECT RESULT: %d\n", result);
    //read input data
    if(result > 0) {

        if(FD_ISSET(arg->sock, &readfds)) {
            bytes_read = read(arg->sock, buf,
```

`FD_ISSET()` returns false.

Comment: Supposing that all the arguments to `select()` and to the `fd_set` manipulation functions / macros satisfy their preconditions, the behavior you describe is inconsistent with the documentation of `select()`.  If you really observe what you say then you should file a bug report, but I'm inclined to suspect that the code you present is not actually representative of your scenario, or perhaps that the results you describe differ from what actually happens.

Comment: Is it possible that another thread is modifying `arg->sock` after `select()` exits and before `FD_ISSET()` is called? If not, then what you describe is simply not possible. `select()` cannot return > 0 if `readfds` is empty.

Comment: You should provide more proof that what you say is happening actually happens. e.g. what did `printf("SELECT RESULT: %d\n", result);` actually display on your screen ? What do you see when you add more debug output, such as printing out `printf("FD_ISSET(%d) %d\n", arg->sock, FD_ISSET(arg->sock, &readfds));` which you should add to your code after the `if(result > 0) {` (if your implementation is a single threaded server and you use a web browser to test, remember that the browser might set up multiple connection, which will certainly not work with this kind of code)

Comment: this kind of odd event can happen if the variable `arg->sock` is less than 0.   Have you been checking the returned values from the functions called to get to this point in the code?   if this is part of a server code, why have you not used `listen()` and `accept()`  rather than `select()`?

Comment: @user3629249: [according to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351338/), this code is part of a thread that is started after a client is accepted.

Comment: Thank you, Remy Lebeau. So yes, the problem is that other thread modifying socket. I just add sleep(1) and main function now wait for the thread execution.